# assign value to a variable using eval in a metaprogramming manner

Tags: python, eval, metaprogramming

I want to assign value to a variable using eval in a metaprogramming manner. My attempt was shown below:

```py
sample = None
var_name = "sample"
value = 0
eval("{0} = {1}".format(var_name, value))
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 4, in <module>
    eval("{0} = {1}".format(var_name, value))
  File "<string>", line 1
    sample = 0
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you explain how can I do this? I think lower level function like `assign(var, val)` could exist and this enabled assignment using eval. But I couldn't find such function.

Comment: Python's `eval` function evaluates expressions.  It doesn't execute statements.  Assignment is a statement, not an expression.  That explains the problem you're having.  In general. making a global change using eval is A Really Bad Idea.

Comment: `exec` does what you want.

Comment: But whatever it is you're trying to do, please don't do it.  You are creating a massive security hole in your program.  Whatever it is you're actually trying to accomplish, there are better and safer ways.

Comment: hmm, I'm modifying exisiting software, and to keep the backward compatibility and adding my feature, using the metaprogramming seems the only way...

Comment: @orematasaburo no, almost certainly, using `eval` or `exec` is not the right way. If you actually described your problem we may be able to point you in the right direction

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are right. After half hour later, I found much simpler approach without metaprogramming stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exec` instead:

```py
sample = None
var_name = "sample"
value = 0
exec("{0} = {1}".format(var_name, value))
```

`eval` is for evaluating an expression, not an assignment statement

Answer (score 0):

does [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html) accomplish what you're trying to do?:

```
sample = None
var_name = "sample"
value = 5
exec(f"{var_name} = {value}")

print(sample)
```

output: `5`

Answer (score 0):

If you're outside a function you can use

```py
globals()[varname] = value
```

Example:

```py
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> globals()['a'] = 5
>>> a
5
```

Inside a function there's `locals()` but it can only read from the symbol table and not update so you should use `eval()` like other answers have pointed out.

You can also cheat by using setattr/hasattr/getattr on an object:

```py
>>> class Object:
...     pass
... 
>>> obj = Object()
>>> obj.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> setattr(obj, 'a', 3)
>>> obj.a
3
```

Comment: neither `eval` nor `exec` will update the local sybol table